# vector to non vector assignment in cpp

Tags: c++, loops, object, vector, iterator

I am getting error on `data *c=it;`. I need to retrieve only one value.

```
class X
{
    string value4;
    vector<data> *T1;
}
class data
{
    string value1;
    int value2;
}
void doTask(X V1)
{
    vector<data> *tempdata=V1.getData();
    for (std::vector<data>::iterator it = tempdata->begin() ; it !=tempdata->end(); ++it)
    {
              data *c=it;
              sendData(value3,c);
    }
}
 void sendData(string s,data d)
{

}
```

I am getting this error:

> error: cannot convert 'std::vector::iterator {aka
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' to 'data*' in initialization

I am new in this vector usage. Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: Why do you assume a `std::vector::iterator` is assignable to a `data*`?

Comment: The vector doesn't store pointers to `data` but instances, so  it makes no sense in making a variable such as `c` a pointer.

Comment: **–1** This is **not the real code**. For example, class definitions sans semicolons won't compile.

Comment: voting to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: Also, having a pointer to a vector often doesn't make much sense either. The more C++ evolves, the less pointers are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dereference the iterator to get a reference to the contained item type, then get its address to get a pointer:

```
data *c = &*it;
```

Comment: or `data & c = *it;` or even better, `sendData(value3, *it);`

Comment: Yep.  Also, sendData should take a pointer to d.

Comment: No, it should be a reference. Unless you have good reason where d could be null.
`void sendData(const std::string & s, const data & a)`

Comment: Well, either the function should take a reference, and a reference should be passed to it, or the function should take a pointer, and a pointer should be passed to it.

Comment: But the call to sendData isn't directly related to the error message that the question is asking about.